# How to create a guest-session in Kubuntu 14.04 (kdm)

Tags: kubuntu, login, kdm

I would like to add a guest-session on a computer with Kubuntu 14.04 LTS and KDM as login manager.

The guest account should be non persistent like in Ubuntu 12.04 (account uses only  /tmp file)

I've found this [Guide to a guest session on login screen](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1601911) for Ubuntu 10.10 but is it still applicable for a recent Kubuntu ? I'd think there is  a more direct method.

NB: A guest-session has a higher security settings by default,  it doesn't allow access to filesystem files and all files are deleted upon logout since they're stored on /tmp.

NB2: kdm is used as login manager instead of lightdm on this computer

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a pre-set guest session, but the preset guest session will not save the guest data... You can access the pre-set guest session in the login menu when the computer boots up,or in the gear shaped power icon in the top right hand corner of your desktop.It will say Guest Session.

if you want to create a new user for the guest, instead of using the preset guest session.Open a terminal via [ctrl]+[alt]+[t] and enter the following commands.

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

then fill out the following questions that your terminal will ask.

create unix password for the user.

where it asks to enter full name enter- guest-session or whatever preferred user name.

you can skip the following questions about phone and room numbers if you choose by pressing [enter].

it will ask you if you information is correct and to enter y/n for yes or no enter preferred command either y or n and press [enter].

Presto you have created a new user.

This method can also be used to create users for specific people of household members by the way.

So I wish you luck and hope that i was helpful,have a wonderful day.

TAC_Tux

Comment: @TAC_Tuc, I appreciated your answer and your time. However my point is that I don't have a pre-set guest-session nor "guest" user (I don't know if it is linked to use of kdm instead of lightdm). I am not looking to create an new regular user but a one with "guest-session" attributes (non persistent account).

Comment: I dont know what to tell ya then...if its not there than you probably wont be able to get it on there.